# Date formatting using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am having an application which uses oracle as backend. what is the correct format  while passing the parameters to stored procedure from c sharp? If the format is **dd-mmm-yyyy**. i.e **30-jan-2011**. How to convert a date which is in **mm/dd/yyyy (01/30/2011)** to **dd-mmm-yyyy (30-jan-2011)**?

Answer (score 2):

You should load the value into a `DateTime` type with a parse, and output with a `ToString()`

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact("01/30/2011","mm/dd/yyyy");
string readyForOracle = d.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

ParseExact method docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx

DateTime custom formatting docs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could use :

```
dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

dt being your DateTime variable

Answer (score 0):

Date formatting described on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).

Will be something like this:

```
DateTime dt = ...; //Getting your date.
string newFormat = dt.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.Format("{0:mm/dd/yyyy}", date);  // 01/30/2011
String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", date);  // 30-jan-2011
```

Answer (score 0):

Its string.format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", date)